# instance of de un genérico

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo verificar si un objeto es de la misma clase o subclase que un objeto de tipo genérico?

```
public class SingleLinkedList<Type> implements MyList<Type> {
private Node<Type> root;

    // ay muchas cosas wuuuuuu!!

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o){
        return o instanceof Class<Type> ? containsSameTypeVerified(o): false;
    }

   public boolean containsSameTypeVerified(Type o) {
    if (root == null && o == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Node<Type> currentNode = root;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.equals(o))
                return true;
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Mi interfaz de lista

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface MyList<Type> extends Collection<Type> {
    boolean contains(Object object);
    // ay muchas cosas wuuuuuu!!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He hallado la solución!

Pasos:

1. validar que el parámetro no sea nulo
2. validar que validar que el objeto del tipo  no sea nul
3. validar que las clases sean las mismas
4. si son las mismas convertir y proceder

   `@Override public boolean contains(Object o) {
       return null!=o && null !=root && o.getClass().equals(root.getItem().getClass())
           && containsSameTypeVerified((Type) o);
     }`

Comment: Desde **Java 7**  puedes comprobar si un objeto es nulo para evitar *NPE* con: `Objects.isNull( o )`

Comment: Lo sé, pero prefiero la comparación a la antigüita y no lanzar una excepción si no es necesario.

Comment: Es una opción más. Con `Objects.isNull( o )` y `Objects.nonNull( o )` obtienes un booleano, el que lanzaría una excepción directamente creo que es *requireNonNull*

Comment: vaya, me confundí. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Teoricamente en java `instance of` tambien da true si comparas una clase padre tanto consigo misma como con una clase hija suya.

Comment: lo sé, pero eso no responde a la pregunta, favor de tomar en cuenta los genéricos

Comment: Creo que ya me acuerdo, creo que hay que poner `instanceof Class<?>`

Comment: compila, pero el comportamiento es incorrecto con `Class<?>`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear una variable del tipo de clase:

```
Class<Type> type;
```

Y luego en contains puedes hacer:

```
type.isInstance(o);
```

O esto:

```
type.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass());
```

Comment: eso produciría un NPE